# How can I combine flexbox and vertical scroll in a full-height app?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to use a full-height app using flexbox. I found what I want using old flexbox layout module (`display: box;` and other things) in this link: [CSS3 Flexbox full-height app and overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251447/css3-flexbox-full-height-app-and-overflow)

This is a correct solution for browsers that only support the old version of the flexbox CSS properties.

If I want to try using the newer flexbox properties, I'll try to use the second solution in the same link listed as a hack: using a container with `height: 0px;`. It makes to show a vertical scroll.

I don't like it a lot because it introduces other problems and it is more a workaround than a solution.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;    
}
#container {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 height: 100%;
}
#container article {
 flex: 1 1 auto;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}
#container header {
    background-color: gray;
}
#container footer {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<section id="container" >
    <header id="header" >This is a header</header>
    <article id="content" >
        This is the content that
        <br />
        With a lot of lines.
        <br />
        With a lot of lines.
        <br />
        This is the content that
        <br />
        With a lot of lines.
        <br />
        <br />
        This is the content that
        <br />
        With a lot of lines.
        <br />
        <br />
        This is the content that
        <br />
        With a lot of lines.
        <br />
    </article>
    <footer id="footer" >This is a footer</footer>
</section>
```

I have prepared a JSFiddle as well with a base example: http://jsfiddle.net/ch7n6/

It is a full-height HTML website and the footer is at the bottom because of the flexbox properties of the content element. I suggest you move the bar between CSS code and result to simulate different height.

Comment: This isn't the behavior you're looking for?  http://jsfiddle.net/ch7n6/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ch7n6/3/ Yes! It is. :D But I can't understand why I need to indicate a height to obtain the effect. Anyway setting: **height: 1px;** works

Comment: Now I changed the height to a min-height. Much better. Thanks you.

Comment: @JoséCabo +1 - nice trick height:0 to show vertical scroll! Could you explain **why** this works?

Comment: My answer to my question (the second answer for this question) I do my best to explain it. In reality what you want to do is use min-height instead of height for a "semantic" answer... but in reality is what the standard said.

Comment: Dear @MikePhils, have you read this post?

Comment: You should apply `flex-shrink:0` to both header and footer.

Comment: @Z.Neeson Yes, you are right. Perhaps I should update the question's answer to change the flex: auto and set it to 0 (or the right value). The thing is that at that time my flex knowledge was not as good as today.

Answer (score 351, accepted):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1652962/cimmanon that gave me the answer.

The solution is setting a height to the vertical scrollable element. For example:

```css
#container article {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 0px;
}
```

The element **will** have height because flexbox recalculates it unless you want a *min-height* so you can use `height: 100px;` that it is exactly the same as: `min-height: 100px;`

```css
#container article {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100px; /* == min-height: 100px*/
}
```

So the best solution if you want a `min-height` in the vertical scroll:

```css
#container article {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

If you just want full vertical scroll in case there is no enough space to see the article:

```css
#container article {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    min-height: 0px;
}
```

The final code: http://jsfiddle.net/ch7n6/867/

Comment: Using `min-height`in Chrome does not work, it affects the size of the footer somehow. Using `height` however, gives the desired result.

Comment: Try to place that heigh in where the "auto". I have studied this and I think the right place is this property. So instead of using min-height and height use it.

Comment: `height: 0` fixed some 2px jumping when content is overflowing vs when it's not. So weird. Thanks anway.

Comment: @Sumit, can you provide a picture of what problem are you facing?

Comment: I opened the fiddle link and doesn't seem to be working anymore on Chrome (works in Firefox). The scroll bar disappeared. Does anyone have an idea how to get this working again?

Comment: The scroll bar is there but invisible. That has to do nothing with the css flexbox but with the style that Chrome is applying. Do scroll and you will see the scroll bar appear. Tested with latest Chrome version in macOS.

Comment: This does not hide the address bar in Chrome

Comment: @RichardLindhout the address bar is never mentioned in the question as any type of requirement, why do you bring it up?

Comment: @ErikPhilips because it's a disadvantage of this solution, could be interesting to know for some users. especially when you're building a mobile website, the address bar is a lot of space for some of the mobile screens.

Comment: nvm I wasn't setting the html height to 100% only the body. Makes perfect sense

Comment: My content is hidden, `height: 0px;` is not dynamically changed... I got a 0-height box :D

Comment: I'll never understand CSS. But hey, it works a charm! Thanks for preventing me pulling my hear out!

Answer (score 84):

Flexbox spec editor here.

This is an encouraged use of flexbox, but there are a few things you should tweak for best behavior.

- Don't use prefixes. Unprefixed flexbox is well-supported across most browsers.  Always start with unprefixed, and only add prefixes if necessary to support it.
- Since your header and footer aren't meant to flex, they should both have `flex: none;` set on them.  Right now you have a similar behavior due to some overlapping effects, but you shouldn't rely on that unless you want to accidentally confuse yourself later. (Default is `flex:0 1 auto`, so they start at their auto height and can shrink but not grow, but they're also `overflow:visible` by default, which triggers their default `min-height:auto` to prevent them from shrinking at all. If you ever set an `overflow` on them, the behavior of `min-height:auto` changes (switching to zero rather than min-content) and they'll suddenly get squished by the extra-tall `<article>` element.)
- You can simplify the `<article>` `flex` too - just set `flex: 1;` and you'll be good to go.  Try to stick with the common values in https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/#flex-common unless you have a good reason to do something more complicated - they're easier to read and cover most of the behaviors you'll want to invoke.

Comment: flex: none; saved me
It was what helped me have a flex element take the entire height of its children and ignore the height 100% of its parent (had 100% on a parent in order to use overflow)

Answer (score 22):

The current spec says this regarding `flex: 1 1 auto`:

> Sizes the item based on the `width`/`height` properties, but makes
>   them fully flexible, so that they absorb any free space along the main
>   axis. If all items are either `flex: auto`, `flex: initial`, or `flex:
>   none`, any positive free space after the items have been sized will be
>   distributed evenly to the items with `flex: auto`.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-css3-flexbox-20120918/#flex-common

It sounds to me like if you say an element is 100px tall, it is treated more like a "suggested" size, not an absolute.  Because it is allowed to shrink and grow, it takes up as much space as its allowed to.  That's why adding this line to your "main" element works:  `height: 0` (or any other smallish number).