# How can I make Flexbox children 100% height of their parent?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to fill the vertical space of a flex item inside a Flexbox.

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.flex-1 {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.flex-2 {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}
.flex-2-child {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-1"></div>
  <div class="flex-2">
    <div class="flex-2-child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ZDuE/)

`flex-2-child` doesn't fill the required height except in the two cases where:

1. `flex-2` has a height of 100% (which is weird because a flex item has a 100% by default + it is buggy in Chrome)
2. `flex-2-child` has a position absolute which is also inconvenient

This doesn't work in Chrome or Firefox currently.

Comment: what is the problem with using height:100%; for .flex-2 ?

Comment: It defies the purpose of the flex item which is to fill the content by itself and it's giving me the weirdest bug in chrome where the height goes back to zero whenever I resize the window

Comment: Firefox versions that still follow the spec from 2009 (display: box) behave very differently from versions that follow the modern spec.  If FF is misbehaving, I'd recommend dropping support for it.

Comment: Actually, the latest version of Firefox is the only one working properly

Comment: Currently, there are significant differences in behavior among browsers when it comes to rendering percentage heights in flexbox: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35537510/3597276

Comment: Yep, Chrome has some issues, especially with nested flexboxes. For example I've got a nested flex box with children that have `height:100%` but they are rendering with natural height instead. And the weird thing is if I change their height to `auto`, then they render as `height:100%` like I was trying to do. It is definitely not intuitive if that's how it should work.

Comment: It doesn't work at all...

Comment: Looks like in 2022 height 100% works on flex children now.

Answer (score 885, accepted):

### Use `align-items: stretch`

Similar to David Storey's answer, my workaround is:

```
.flex-2 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}
```

Note that `height: 100%` should be removed from the child component (see comments).

Alternatively to `align-items`, you can use `align-self` just on the `.flex-2-child` item you want stretched.

Comment: `stretch`: this should be the chosen answer.

Comment: How would you align the text inside a div that has been stretched to vertically align in the middle tho?

Comment: Yes you should add removing `height: 100%`

Comment: This saved my day. I got a flex row which has some items. I want these items to take height from its parent. I demonstrated my issue here https://codepen.io/dshung1997/pen/LYxvXNy

Comment: Will this work if we have no control over "container" in this example? In other words, I can't make "container" use flex layout

Comment: @void.pointer Probably not. align-items only works in flex boxes as far as I know.

Comment: @astigmatik set "align-self: stretch" only for a child item you want to take 100% height and for parent "align-item: center"

Comment: This is not a workaround, this is exactly how it should be done, the parent container should be flex and set to stretch its childrens. Thats the whole philosophy of flexbox, it aligns and sizes its children.

Comment: It just seems silly that height: 100% doesn't work. I regard that as a failing of css - whether its a bug or a design flaw.

Comment: for me, align-self:stretch worked but align-items:stretch didn't

Comment: "Note that height: 100% should be removed from the child component" this line was time savior for me, thanks

Answer (score 295):

I know you have already said `position: absolute;` is inconvenient, but it works. See below for further information on fixing the resize issue.

Also see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poztin/MFHj7/1/) for a demo, although I have only added WebKit prefixes so open in Chrome.

You basically have two issues which I will deal with separately.

1. **Getting the child of a flex-item to fill height 100%**

- Set `position: relative;` on the parent of the child.
- Set `position: absolute;` on the child.
- You can then set width/height as required (100% in my sample).

2. **Fixing the resize scrolling "quirk" in Chrome**

- Put `overflow-y: auto;` on the scrollable div.
- The scrollable div must have an explicit height specified. My sample already has height 100%, but if none is already applied you can specify `height: 0;`

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14964944/295813) for more information on the scrolling issue.

Comment: Point 1) works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox doesn't need the position absolute.

Comment: This is not an acceptable solution. In all my years of programming I've learned you only use position absolute very carefully for some things, as elements may not render correctly in other browsers. Plus the answer isn't addressed, as he mentioned Flexbox right there in the Title, so this answer is wrong.

Comment: @MannyAlvarado this question and answer were posted at a time when flexbox was still in working draft and browser implementations all over the place. Historical context is important here. Thankfully we're in a better place now which is why better answers have surpassed this one.

Comment: @MannyAlvarado I've been doing this for a while too, but I have not experienced weird browser quirks with `position: absolute` ever (but I have seen them with `flex`...). Paired with `position: relative`, it can be "fluid" a bit like flex, can be useful in some situations.

Answer (score 278):

If I understand correctly, you want flex-2-child to fill the height and width of its parent, so that the red area is fully covered by the green?

If so, you just need to set flex-2 to use Flexbox:

```
.flex-2 {
    display: flex;
}
```

Then tell flex-2-child to become flexible:

```
.flex-2-child {
    flex: 1;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/2ZDuE/10/

The reason is that flex-2-child is not a Flexbox item, but its parent is.

Comment: How can I do the same, just with a height of 100% and every child is 50/50 ?

Comment: Be aware that if you use "align-items: center" you won't be able to use this fix since your items will now become equal-height.

Comment: @NeilMonroe You can still use `align-items: center` if you use `align-self: stretch` on just the one child.

Comment: Hi @David, i tried your solution, it works fine for the flex-direction: row layout, it seems not working with flex-direction: column layout, or i have any places wrong in the code. Could you help to check why in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/78o54Lmv/, the inner box won't occupy the full height of its parent?

Comment: I have to add `min-height: 100vh;` to `.flex-2` element to make it works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @NeilMonroe Thanks! I always forget this until I come across your comment.

Answer (score 36):

I found the solution by myself. Suppose you have the CSS below:

```
.parent {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child {
  height: 100%; <- didn't work
}
```

In this case, setting the height 100% will not work, so I set the `margin-bottom` rule to `auto`, like:

```
.child {
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

And the child will be aligned to the topmost of the parent.

You can also use the `align-self` rule anyway if you prefer:

```
.child {
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: A nice hack, but the problem is: if child is a sidebar and it have a background color, the margin space is still white.

Comment: What's great about this solution is that the height of the parent can be dynamic! The previous solutions require the parent to have a set height. Thanks for this.

Comment: problem is i need a border to go all tlhe way down to the bottom

Answer (score 28):

I suppose that Chrome's behavior is more consistent with the CSS specification (though it's less intuitive). According to Flexbox specification, the default `stretch` value of `align-self` property [changes only the *used* value](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#align-stretch) of the element's "cross size property" (`height`, in this case). And, as I understand [the CSS 2.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#x12), the percentage heights are calculated from the *specified* value of the parent's `height`, not its used value. The specified value of the parent's `height` isn't affected by any flex properties and is still `auto`.

Setting an explicit `height: 100%` makes it *formally* possible to calculate the percentage height of the child, just like setting `height: 100%` to `html` makes it possible to calculate the percentage height of `body` in CSS 2.1.

Comment: Exactly! To put this into practice, just add `height:100%` to `.flex-2`. Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZDuE/114/).

Comment: Chrome's behavior is more consistent with *Chrome Team's interpretation of* the CSS spec. While it could be interpreted that way, there are far better ways of interpreting it, any of which wouldn't have trapped us into this bazaar, annoying, and irksome behavior. They should have thought it through more.

Comment: @RickDoesburg, this was more than a year ago, but I believe that I had to resort to fixed height elements. I wish these browsers would get their act together. I'm really starting to dislike the mobile space.

Comment: Setting a child of a vertical flexbox container to `height: 100%` is giving very odd results for me in Chrome.  It seems that this causes the "specified height" to be set to the *total height of the container*, rather than the height of the element itself, so causes unwanted scrolling when other elements have sizes calculated relative to it.

Answer (score 11):

This can also be solved with `align-self: stretch;` on the element we want to be stretched.

Sometimes it is desirable to only stretch one item in a Flexbox setup.

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.flex-1 {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.flex-2 {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  align-self: stretch;
  background-color: red;
}
.flex-2-child {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-1"></div>
  <div class="flex-2">
    <div class="flex-2-child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is what i want 

for tailwind lib

```
       <div
          className="flex-1 flex items-start justify-center "
        >
          <div className="flex-1" />
          <div className="flex-1 relative self-stretch" />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Another approach (other option wouldn't fit my case because I needed a more generic solution, I really want to avoid using `position: absolute` when possible, and just `display: flex` with `align-items: stretch` wouldn't work in my case because of other syling):

1. Have a parent with `display: flex`
2. Give your element display flex as well, `align-self: stretch` and `margin-top: 0` + `margin-bottom: 0`

Minimal reproducible example:

```css
.parrent {
  display: flex;
}
.full-height-just-with-bg-collor {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-self: stretch;
  // this can be just 0 or you can set just the top and bottom values
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="parrent">
    <div class="full-height-just-with-bg-collor"></div> 
    textForHeight
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
}

.child {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.child {
    align-self: stretch;
}
```

Based on previous answers got this solution to work for full height flex elements.

Answer (score 5):

An idea would be that `display:flex;` with `flex-direction: row;` is filling the `container` div with `.flex-1` and `.flex-2`, but that does not mean that `.flex-2` has a default `height:100%;`, even if it is extended to full height.

And to have a child element (`.flex-2-child`) with `height:100%;`, you'll need to set the parent to `height:100%;` or use `display:flex;` with `flex-direction: row;` on the `.flex-2` div too.

From what I know, `display:flex` will not extend all your child elements height to 100%.

A small demo, removed the height from `.flex-2-child` and used `display:flex;` on `.flex-2`:
http://jsfiddle.net/2ZDuE/3/

Answer (score 5):

```css
.container {
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-flexbox;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -moz-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.flex-1 {
   flex:1 0 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.flex-2 {
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -moz-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1 0 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
.flex-2-child {
    flex: 1 0 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="flex-1"></div>
    <div class="flex-2">
        <div class="flex-2-child"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2ZDuE/750/

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 4):

fun fact: height-100% works in the latest chrome; but not in safari;

---

so solution in tailwind would be

## "flex items-stretch"

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/align-items

and be applied recursively to the child's child's child ...

Answer (score -8):

.container {
    . . . . 
    align-items: stretch;
    . . . .
}

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You need to fully explain your answer, and what it contributes that is different from the existing answers. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Your answer seems to be the same as B T's (written over three years early) but expressed far more poorly.

Answer (score -14):

This is my solution using [css+](http://www.css.plus).

First of all, if the first child (flex-1) should be 100px, it shouldn't be flex.

In [css+](http://www.css.plus) in fact you can set flexible and/or static elements (columns or rows) and your example become as easy as this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="EXTENDER">
    <div class="COLS">
      <div class="CELL _100px" style="background-color:blue">100px</div>
      <div class="CELL _FLEX" style="background-color:red">flex</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Container CSS:

```
.container {
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
}
```

And obviously include [css+ 0.2 core](https://github.com/hicTech/cssPlus/blob/master/css/build/core.css).

Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dL5eujkk/).