# Nested flexboxes works differently across browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, html, flexbox

I have a small example of a nested flexbox setup: http://jsfiddle.net/ThomasSpiessens/MUrPj/12/

In this example the following applies:

- CSS 'box' classes use flexbox properties on which only the boxContent is told to grow. For specific CSS properties and values, please check the fiddle.
- 'fullSize' just sets both width and height to 100%.

When you check this fiddle with Firefox and Chrome you get different results. In Firefox it does what I would suppose it has to do, which is stretching the inner .boxContent. In Chrome however, the inner .boxContent doesn't get stretched.

Would anyone have an idea how to make the content stretch in Chrome as well ? perhaps a specific webkit property that is missing ?

```css
.fullSize {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: brown;
}


/* line 7, ../../app/styles/_layout.scss */

.boxHeader {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: green;
}


/* line 12, ../../app/styles/_layout.scss */

.boxContent {
  -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1.0;
  background-color: yellow;
}


/* line 18, ../../app/styles/_layout.scss */

.boxFooter {
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.moreblue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.moregreen {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box fullSize">
  <div class="boxHeader">HEADER</div>
  <div class="boxContent">
    <div class="box fullSize">
      <div class="boxHeader moregreen">INNER HEADER</div>
      <div class="boxContent red">CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT</div>
      <div class="boxFooter moreblue">INNER FOOTER</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="boxFooter">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Unless you *need* that extra div, remove it.  There is sometimes a difference between the height of an element and its length along the *main axis* (column orientation), which is causing some confusion here.  Basically, it *looks* like it is taller than the browser believes it to be, which is why `height: 100%` doesn't work like you expect (I'm not certain which behavior is correct in this instance).

For whatever reason, promoting the element to a *flex container* works.

http://jsfiddle.net/MUrPj/14/

```
<div class="box fullSize">
    <div class="boxHeader">HEADER</div>
    <div class="boxContent box">
        <div class="boxHeader moregreen">INNER HEADER</div>
        <div class="boxContent red">CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT</div>
        <div class="boxFooter moreblue">INNER FOOTER</div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxFooter">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked for me. Couldn't get the wrapper div to stretch under any circumstances. Got rid of it and worked fine. Kind of annoying.

Comment: Excellent!  This was a life-saver. :)

Answer (score 14):

This question has been linked for a specific problem: *How to make nested elements in a flex box fill the whole height?* The short answer is:

Use `display:flex` on the child and avoid `height:100%`. Here is a [simplified example on codepen](http://codepen.io/ldwg/pen/vGLqgW).

[CourtDemone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20959601/2567731) explained it well (more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381172/css-flexbox-child-height-100)):

> According to the flexbox spec, an `align-self:stretch` value (the default for a flex'd element) changes only the *used* value of an element's cross-size property (in this case, height). Percentages however are calculated from the *specified* value of the parent's cross-size property, not it's used value.

Comment: it worked for me, div container (flex) had rows, rows had two elements/cells. first elem is fixed width, second was to fill the whatever remaining width. `display:flex` on row did the magic.

Answer (score 4):

I've found a solution without removing the extra-div.

You need to make boxContent relative positioned and its containing box absolute.

With attaching an extra css class to the inner div:

```
<div class="boxContent">
    <div class="box fullSize innerBox">
```

and following css:

```
.boxContent {
  ...
    position: relative;
}
.innerBox{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

here's the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MUrPj/223/

This question is pretty old, but this might be helpful for future visitors

Comment: Thanx man, the best solution in my case, where nested elements must be inline-blocks

Answer (score 2):

[This JsFiddle](https://codepen.io/mappingsteve/pen/bGGBrmp) is the minimum needed CSS attributes to get nested flexboxes to work. I've shown it for *column*; if you are doing this within a *row*, remove the two "flex-direction: column"s. [In this trivial example, removing those won't change anything, because there is only one child of each flexbox. But as soon as you add a second child, you'll be working in either a row or a column.]

HTML:

```
<div id="e1">
  <div id="e2">
    <div id="e3">    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, #e1 {
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
}
#e1 {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#e2 {
  background-color: #ffff00;
  /* Won't work if remove either of the next 2 lines - a box collapses. */
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#e3 {
  background-color: #00ff00;
  flex: 1;
}
```

In my experience, Safari 13 (both MacOS and iOS) is more finicky (re nested flex items) than Chrome 77, Firefox 69, or even Edge 18.
While in *this simple* example, all 3 react the same, I had a more complex situation which worked in all but Safari. Nevertheless, the code shown here -- especially the two lines in `#e2` after "Won't work if remove either of the next 2 lines" -- is the essence of what made my more complex situation work in Safari.

In addition, if having difficulties, first step is to **remove all "percent" height attributes** within the nested elements. Here, that means `#e1` is permitted to have `height: 100%` - this is within the context of *its* parent, which is *not* a flex container. But `#e2` and `#e3` should *not* declare `%` heights.

Having nested elements with **heights that are not relative to their parent** (pixels, ems, vh) are fine, AFAIK.  Note that vh works, because it is relative to window size, which isn't affected by the nested flex containers' (#e1, #e2) heights. So that calculation logic is easy for browser to get right.

---

As requested, [example of nesting four deep](https://codepen.io/mappingsteve/pen/ZEErbRQ). Uses class names to make it easier.

HTML:

```
<div class="fb-outer">
  <div class="fb-middle">
    <div class="fb-middle">
      <div class="fb-inner">    
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, .fb-outer {
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
}
.fb-outer {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.fb-middle {
  background-color: #ffff00;
  /* Won't work if remove either of the next 2 lines. */
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.fb-inner {
  background-color: #00ff00;
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to add one more layer of nesting to that (adding an `e4` as the child of `e3`)?

Comment: Yes, you can go as deep as you want. Make all the "middle" levels the same css as `e2`. To make this easier, use "class names" instead of "ids". Not sure why I used ids. I'll edit the answer to show.

Comment: Thanks! Using that example, I found out that when using Angular components, the host element has to be treated as another fb-middle in order for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

```css
*,*::before,*::after {
margin:0;
padding:0;
box-sizing:border-box;

}
body {
width:100%;
height:100vh;
background-color:purple;
}

.fullSize {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 
}



.box {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: brown;
}

/* line 7, ../../app/styles/_layout.scss */
.boxHeader {
background-color: green;
}

/* line 12, ../../app/styles/_layout.scss */
.boxContent {
  -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1.0;
  background-color: yellow;
}

/* line 18, ../../app/styles/_layout.scss */
.boxFooter {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.moreblue {
    background-color: blue;
}

.moregreen {
    background-color: darkgreen;
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box fullSize">
    <div class="boxHeader">HEADER</div>
    <div class="boxContent">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="boxHeader moregreen">INNER HEADER</div>
                <div class="boxContent red">
                     CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT  
                </div>
                <div class="boxFooter moreblue">INNER FOOTER</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="boxFooter">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i fixed it by removed using a useless class name fullSize that you used secound time on a nested container class="box fullSize"  to class="box"  and given the body {width:100%;height:100vh;} . NOTE: height:100vh; for a body is really important .
ACTUALLY BROWSER OVERRIDES THE .boxContent {-ms-flex: 1 0 auto;-webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;flex: 1 0 auto;-webkit-box-flex: 1.0;background-color: yellow;} ====  WITH === .fullSize {width: 100%;height: 100%;  margin: 0;padding: 0;} .

Comment: Your answer can be improved by providing some insights about the solution you presented.