# Height 100% on flexbox column child

Tags: css, google-chrome, height, percentage, flexbox

I'm having troubles with a flexbox column in that children of the flex'd element don't respond to `height` in percentages. I've only checked this in Chrome, and from what I understand it's a Chrome only problem. Here's my example:

HTML

```
<div class='flexbox'>
  <div class='flex'>
    <div class='flex-child'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='static'></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flexbox{
  position:absolute;
  background:black;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.flex{
  background:blue;
  flex:1;
}

.flex-child{
  background:red;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  display:block;
}

.static{
  background:green;
  width:100%;
  height:5rem;
}
```

[Here's the CodePen.](http://codepen.io/CourtDemone/pen/acLBG)

I want it so the red `.flex-child` fills the blue `.flex`. Why doesn't `height:100%` work?

Comment: As of 2018-04-19, your CodePen works as is.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Set `.flex` to `display:flex`, and get rid of the `height:100%` on `.flex-child`. [You can see the modified CodePen here.](http://codepen.io/CourtDemone/pen/IfEvy)

**Why it works:**

I learned from [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381172/css-flexbox-child-height-100) that, according to the flexbox spec, an `align-self:stretch` value (the default for a flex'd element) changes only the *used value* of an element's cross-size property (in this case, `height`). Percentages however are calculated from the *specified value* of the parent's cross-size property, not it's used value. If you ever crack open your Inspector and see `height:100%` under 'Styles' but `height:1200px` under 'Computed', then that's showing you the *specified* and *used* values respectively.

It seems that Chrome follows the spec to the tee in this respect. That means that setting `height:100%` on `.flex-child` means 100% of the specified `height` of `.flex`. Since we haven't specified a `height` on `.flex`, that means we're grabbing 100% of the default `height`, which is `auto`. See why the layout engine is getting confused?

Setting `.flex` to `display:flex` and removing the `height:100%` from `.flex-child` (so that it doesn't keep trying to set 100% of `auto`) will make `.flex-child` fill all of `.flex`

**When this won't work:**

This won't work if you're trying to fill only some of `.flex`, ex. trying to set `.flex-child` to `height:90%`, because flexing the child means that it'll fill all the available space. I thought you might be able to hack it with absolute positioning, but that doesn't seem to work either. You could hack by adding a second child to `.flex` that we'll call `.spacer`, and setting `.spacer` to `flex:1` and `.flex-child` to `flex:9` (be sure to set `flex-direction:column` on `.flex` too). A hack, but the only way I could fix it. [Here's the CodePen.](http://codepen.io/CourtDemone/pen/sKchk)

Hopefully we don't have to keep relying on this though and they'll just change the spec to act more as expected.

Comment: What happens If the structure is deeply nested, would one have to keep applying — `display:flex` till the very end?

Comment: @Tushar My guess is yes, though I wouldn't know without digging into it. It's also possible that current specs for flexbox or implementations on Chrome account for this issue, since this answer was posted when flexbox was still relatively new.

Comment: I've read the spec, and it seems that the chrome team are just taking a different interpretation of a paragraph then I would have. I'm not sure the spec needs to change so much as needs to be clarify to remove the possibility of this problematic interpretation.

Comment: I wanted to add that setting the `flex-basis: 1px` or `flex: 1 1 1px` on the `.flex` allows you to use `height: 100%` on `.flex-child`. Now what might be the better choice -
 `display: flex` or `flex-basis: 1px`?

Comment: Fails when the inner content of `.flex-child` is taller than its *height*. This solution is not recommended