# CSS: 9 Responsive Cells that Fills the Whole Page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, ionic-framework

I want 9 **responsive** `<div>` cells that fills the whole page like images below:

http://oi57.tinypic.com/2hf5lrk.jpg

I am using **[ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com/)**. If the framework can help, please provide me an example. If not, the pure css would be great too.

Comment: Please share your code... we'd love to help, but won't script it for you from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, see: http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid-even

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">1</div>
  <div class="col">2</div>
  <div class="col">3</div>
</div><div class="row">  
  <div class="col">4</div>
  <div class="col">5</div>
  <div class="col">6</div>
</div><div class="row">
  <div class="col">7</div>
  <div class="col">8</div>
  <div class="col">9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Bass. The only problem is that the rows are not 100% height of the page.

Comment: ionic uses the flex box to build the grid, so consider http://css-tricks.com/boxes-fill-height-dont-squish/,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381172/css-flexbox-child-height-100 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959600/height-100-on-flexbox-column-child

Comment: Thanks for your help. You provide me some codes and examples instead of -1 me. Thanks again.