# Flex aligner working on Firefox/Edge, not on Chrome

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I can't make a aligner working with Chrome, yet it's working on both Firefox and Edge.

I am using flex CSS:

```
body {
      min-height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    wrapper {
      height: 100%;
      /* flex: 1; would be enough but it looks bad in IE */
      flex: 1 0 auto;
      background-color: #3D9970;
    }

    .aligner {
        height:100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .aligner-center {
        max-width: 50%;
        background-color: #ffb443;
        padding: 20px;
    }
```

You see result [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4o7h911s/1/)

I also tried with `display:table` with no success.

Any idea how to align center my Login Form div with Chrome too?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is expected behavior in Chrome as it has a stricter implementation of the [**`Flexbox spec`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-items-property) ([take a look at this thread too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959600/height-100-on-flexbox-column-child)):

1. The default stretch value of `align-self` property changes only the *used  value* of the element's `cross size` property (`height` in this case).
2. Percentages are calculated from the *explicitly specified value* of the parent's `cross-size` property, not it's *used value*.

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing
>   block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
>   height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value
>   computes to 'auto' ([`Source: W3C`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#x12)).

That means that setting `height:100%` on `aligner` which is the child of `wrapper` (in turn the flex child of a `flexbox`). Since we haven't specified a height on `wrapper`, that means it will pick 100% of the *default height*, which is `auto`.

**Solution**:

One of the solutions is to make your `wrapper` a `flexbox` too and give `width: 100%` for the `aligner` - see demo below:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  /* flex: 1; would be enough but it looks bad in IE */
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background-color: #3D9970;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.aligner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.aligner-center {
  max-width: 50%;
  background-color: #ffb443;
  padding: 20px;
}
body {
  font: 16px/1.5 sans-serif;
}
p {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
header,
wrapper,
footer {
  padding: 2em;
  color: white;
}
header {
  background-color: #85144B;
}
footer {
  background-color: #001F3F;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Header
</header>
<wrapper>
  <div class="aligner">
    <div class="aligner-center">
      Login Form
    </div>
  </div>
</wrapper>
<footer>
  Footer
</footer>
```

Comment: Yes that works fine.Thanks :) I have updated the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4o7h911s/2/)

Comment: I integrated it to my website and now evey thing will be center aligned even if I don't use the classes `aligner` `aligner-center`. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/k2t5tvvf/) Any chance to use this flex solution and get an aligned div only if I use the classes `aligner` and `aligner-center` ? Thanks