# CSS flexbox layout: child with height 100%?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to use a 'Holy Grail'-style layout with flexbox - fixed header above columns that fill the page. I am basing my code on [this](https://gist.github.com/jfsiii/5380802) source.

My problem is that a child element with `height:100%` inside of the main cell does not pick up the height of the layout. The following demo shows what I mean, I want the red element to take up the full height (tested in Webkit):

http://jsbin.com/dafac/2/

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/15381172/1807403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the second solution mentioned in [How to make flexbox children 100% height of their parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15381172/1807403) using "position:absolute; bottom:0;" to create a full height child of the flex item because "height:100%" requires the flex item to have an explicit height.

Comment: Thx a lot, I tried editing my jsbin but couldn't see how the solution works? Could you edit the jsbin?