# How to set the height 100% of the flex box item

Tags: css, html, flexbox

I want to set height of child element of flexbox item to 100%. But it doesn't work.

This is the [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/icese7en/qh8k6pft/6/) of these code.

Now, I compromised this solution with setting `position : absolute` and `top : 0; right : 0; bottom : 0; left : 0;` of the inner child element. Can you tell me why the method above cannot work? Is there any solution not doing with `position`.
[image]

Comment: Why so many children? You can't just use two divs, one for each column?

Comment: @misterManSam I need put some content in the child element such as `.wrapper__second__thumb__inner`. Maybe I have wrong used the flexbox?

Comment: It's hard to say :) It looks like you just want two columns [like this example](http://jsbin.com/nufudi/1/edit?html,css,output) but I don't know what outcome you want.

Comment: @misterManSam I have update my post and that is my requirement for outcome. Also, there will be more content like blue area(it can expand out the left side of red area)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using `height: 100%` for `.wrapper__second__thumb__inner`, which is contained inside `.wrapper__thumb` that doesn't have `height` for itself (`0px height`), so `.wrapper__second__thumb__inner` will also have `0px height`.

What you need is to add `height: 100%` to `.wrapper__thumb`, or remove it completely from the `HTML`, so `.wrapper__second__thumb__inner` will have it's `height` directly from the `.wrapper__second`

Here's the [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyojimaru/qh8k6pft/2/)

Comment: @icese7en can you add some picture of how you wanted it to be?

Comment: I already add an image in the question. in the red area i also need to put more content like the blue area(images)

Comment: @icese7en, sorry for the late reply, did you mean something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyojimaru/qh8k6pft/7/)?

Comment: yes, this reproduction is very precise! You can see that, the 100% height of the inner img doesn't work(neither all other elements in the `wrapper__second__thumb__inner`).

Comment: @icese7en the `100% height` of the inner image is working because the real image size is `2880x1800`, but there's no padding set to the `wrapper__second__thumb__inner`, so the `image` cover the `wrapper__second__thumb__inner`. Perhaps [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyojimaru/qh8k6pft/8/) is what you really wanted to have?

Comment: No, if I delete the `float` property of img, it also doesn't work.(even if I set the height of img to 1%)

Comment: @icese7en, this is a problem with the `Browser` I think, I've got the same problem on `Google Chrome` but it's fine for `Firefox`, I think you need to stick with the `position: absolute` way, here's some [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381172/css-flexbox-child-height-100) for reference

Answer (score 0):

Use vh unit for height and vw for width

```
.wrapper {
    display : flex;
    align-items : center;
    flex-flow : row nowrap;
    justify-content : space-between;
    background-color : lightblue;
    width : 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qh8k6pft/3/

more info here : http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Comment: I don't need to expand this block to the whole area of viewport. Just inside the `wrapper__second` container. You could see the latest update of my jsFiddle, there were some errors in early version