# Flexbox: my div has not a full height

Tags: css, flexbox

I just created a website with a very simple design using Flexbox. With Firefox and Chrome, everything works fine but with IE, I have a tiny issue but quite visible. Here is the page: http://www.csharpnet.net/article/introduction. If you check it with Firefox, you'll see that the left aside has a 100% height, but with IE, it is not the case. I checked my CSS over and over and I don't know what to change.

I checked all parent element and they all have a 100% height, so why this aside has not this height as well ?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**: code example and [fiddle with the code](http://jsfiddle.net/zh2w6nfv/)

```
<html style="height:100%;margin:0;">


<body style="height:100%;margin:0;">
    <div style="display:flex;flex-flow:column;height:100%;">



        <div style="background-color:green;flex-grow:1;flew-shrink:1;flex-basis:200px;display:flex;flex-flow:row;">
            <div style="background-color:yellow;flex-basis:700px;flex-grow:1;flew-shrink:1;"></div>
            <div style="background-color:white;flex-basis:100%;flex-grow:1;flew-shrink:1;"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="background-color:red;flex-grow:1;flew-shrink:1;flex-basis:100%;display:flex;flex-flow:row;">
            <div style="background-color:blue;flex-basis:500px;flex-grow:1;flew-shrink:1;"></div>
            <div style="background-color:gray;flex-basis:100%;flex-grow:1;flew-shrink:1;">
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
            </div>              
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Add the code, there is little we can do without it

Comment: which version of IE?

Comment: It is IE11 and for the code... Well, the CSS is on the site, so you can check with F12, it will be easier I think. But if you really prefer, I can copy/paste the CSS in here.

Comment: I just tried from scratch to see where was my error, here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/zh2w6nfv/.

As you can see, as long as you don't scroll down to see all the content, divs have the correct size but it does not grow with the content...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken your code and split the styling to a separate stylesheet, for the ease of troubleshooting. I've also cleaned it, fixed typo's (`flex-flew`) and removed unnecessary code.

Other than that I've used correct terminology and removed flexbox-capabilities where they aren't needed (e.g. `flex: 1 1 200px;` is basically the same as saying `flex: 1; width: 200px;` on a flex-element, but that's up to the individual).

What really did the trick though, was just removing the `height: 100%` and relying solely on flexbox.

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uako2dsj/2/

Remember to prefix, to meet IE in a better way.

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="container">

    <div class="header">
        <div class="yellow"></div>
        <div class="white"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="blue"></div>
        <div class="gray">
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
            <p>aaaa</p>
        </div>              
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
    display:flex;
    height: 200px;

    background-color:green;
}

.yellow {
    width: 700px;

    background-color: yellow;
}

.white {
    width: 200px;
    flex: 1;

    background-color: white;
}

.content {
    display: flex;

    background-color: red;
}
.blue {
    width: 500px;

    background-color: blue;
}
.gray {
    width: 200px;
    flex:1;

    background-color: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've recently run into this same behaviour and found a solution in this thread: [How to make flexbox children 100% height of their parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381172/css-flexbox-child-height-100)

It's the answer posted by "Brett Postin" using the "position:absolute; bottom:0" trick to create a full height container because "height:100%" doesn't work due to the flex box child not using explicit heights to determine its height.

Comment: I notice your question mentions your case only has problems in IE. The issue I mentioned would effect IE & Chrome, my apologies its probably unrelated.