# Flexbox - make flex item child 100% height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

JSFiddle with identical HTML/CSS I'm working with included:
http://jsfiddle.net/pf5bczLe/

How do you make `.box` 100% height of its parent, in this case `.box-wrap`?

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29049715/how-to-control-child-div-height-of-a-flex-item) post its flexbox's item imperfection it doesn't act as 100% height for its children. Is there any other way I could achieve all the items to have the same height although their height is dynamic?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very close in stretching the child elements. Playing with your example, add the following css to `.box-wrap`

```
.box-wrap {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Then add the following to `.box`

```
.box {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
 }
```

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/2xa4r7h3/)

Comment: This seems to break in IE11.