# Flexbox: make child fill 100% height of it's parent in this layout without fixed height or position absolute

Tags: css, flexbox

[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/knitevision1/pen/ZGPEzy?editors=110)

So I've got this very typical layout
`.logo` can be of any height and I need the `nav & ul & li & a` inside the `.container` to take up 100% of it's width.

**SCSS**

```
.logo {
    font-size: 40px;
}

header {
    background-color: tomato;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
    align-items: center;
}

nav {
    margin-left: auto;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;

    li {
        margin-right: 10px;
        &:last-child {
            margin-right: 0;
        }
    }
```

}

**Markup**

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">I'm logo</div>
        <nav role='navigation'>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>  
    </div>
</header>
```

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381172/css-flexbox-child-height-100) but the solutions offer either `position: relative` on parent and `position: absolute` on child, or fixed-height solutions.

**Edit** The goal is to have `a` border-bottom that will be displayed right at the bottom of the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you were after:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.logo {
  font-size: 40px;
}
 .container {
  display: flex;
}
.logo {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background: lightblue;
}
nav {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1
}
li {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
a {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <nav role='navigation'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Clients</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/NqJWBj?editors=110)

Comment: Thanks. But in inspect element ``a`` is still not 100% of the container height. Whilst the main goal is to have ``a`` border-bottom that will be displayed right at the bottom of the container

Comment: Amended...I think this is closer.