# How to make a div not fill the height of its parent?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

There are several questions about [how to make a child `div` the height of its parent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16771324/903011).

I have this behaviour by default and would like to have the inverse: so that the child does **not** fill the height of its parent (cross-axis):

```css
#root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
}

.el {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="el">hello</div>
  <div class="el">world</div>
</div>
```

**What should I do (to the parent? to the child?) so that the height of `hello` and `world` is tight with the text?**

Answer (score 1):

Use `align-items` with a value other than `stretch`

```css
#root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.el {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="el">hello</div>
  <div class="el">world</div>
</div>
```