# Set child element to have 100% height of parent regardless of other siblings

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've got this layout and I need div#loadingpopup to have a 100% height and 100% width of the parent (#jobs), overlaying/ignoring its siblings (.job-listing) so that the content of both div.job-listing is still barely visible through the semi-transparent background of div#loadingpopup. How can that be achieved?

So far I tried setting position:absolute, width and height for 100%; top and left for 0, for #loadingpopup but it works, covering the whole viewport when I needed only #jobs (parent div) to be covered with my #loadingpopup

```html
<div id="jobs">
  <div class="job-listing">
    <h4 class="job__title"> Test </h4><br>
  </div>
  <div class="job-listing">
    <h4 class="job__title"> Test </h4><br>
  </div>
  <div id="loadingpopup" style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.2)">
    <span><i class="fas fa-circle-notch fa-spin" style="margin-right: 16px"></i>Loading...</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make flexbox children 100% height of their parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381172/how-to-make-flexbox-children-100-height-of-their-parent)   (I'm basing that on the fact that the question is tagged "flexbox" -- if you're not using flexbox please include all the relevant CSS you are using on these elements in the question; we can't debug based on partial information.)

Comment: @DanielBeck these questions are similar, only that OP is asking about making one child in flexbox take full height regardless of other siblings, which is unnatural for the flex system and has to be done with a different approach.

Comment: Fair point @Siavas, well spotted.  Retracting my "close" vote (though I'll leave the link in comments as it seems like it might still be useful)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with absolute positioning:

```css
#jobs {
  position: relative;
}

#loadingpopup {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#loadingpopup span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="jobs">
  <div class="job-listing">
    <h4 class="job__title"> Test </h4><br>
  </div>
  <div class="job-listing">
    <h4 class="job__title"> Test </h4><br>
  </div>
  <div id="loadingpopup" style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.2)">
    <span><i class="fas fa-circle-notch fa-spin" style="margin-right: 16px"></i>Loading...</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The tricky part here is that `position: absolute;` will take as reference the first **non-static** parent (having anything else than `position: static` which is default, that is). This means you will need to set `position: relative` to `#jobs` as well.

Once that is done, we can set 100% width and height and do similar absolute positioning for the `span` inside `#loadingpopup`. This can also be achieved with flexbox, using `align-items: flex-end;`, but in this simple scenario we can use the former [for better support](https://www.caniuse.com/#search=flexbox).

You might also want to increase the height by the child's own height, as 100% will only consider the non-absolutely positioned elements. Use `calc(100% + 20px)` or similar to achieve this.

Learn more about [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [`position`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/) properties at CSS Tricks.

Comment: Thanks Siavas! You helped me. The thing was that I needed to add position:relative to my container. You clarified it with your comment on non-static position reference