# Styled Component fill div height inside MUI Grid

Tags: css, material-ui, styled-components

The two cells marked as **pink** becomes pink on mouse hover. How can I fill the grid with pink 100% width & height on mouse hover?

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-comp-listitem-ok7j0?file=/index.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `ListItem` as your grid container (not sure if this is a requirement or it was just easy for you), and by default the `ListItem` component has padding.

You can disable this padding by settings the padding of that component to 0:

```
<ListItem button style={{padding: 0}}>
```

Comment: Can you please take a look at this ;
[sandbox2](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-comp-listitem-ok7j0?file=/demo.tsx)

How to make the pink div full height?

Comment: This is more of a CSS question, but you can use the solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381172/how-can-i-make-flexbox-children-100-height-of-their-parent Check this change to your example: https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-comp-listitem-xzl0s