# React Native: View not covering parent height

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

## Issue

There are 2 tabs stacked horizontally and in the first tab, the view in green color isn’t able to fill the parent's height when the content is different in both the **Tabs**.

[image]

## Reproducible in Expo

https://snack.expo.dev/@vinay-sharma/92706e

## Code

```js
import React from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

const Tab = ({ textNodes }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "red" }}>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: "blue", width: 10 }}></View>

        {/* the green view isn’t able to fill parent's height*/}
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: "green", flex: 1 }}>
          {textNodes.map((node) => (
            <Text>{node}</Text>
          ))}
        </View>
      </View>

      <View style={{ height: 10, backgroundColor: "black" }} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", marginTop: 25 }}>
      <Tab textNodes={[1, 2, 3]} />
      <Tab textNodes={[1, 2, 3, 4]} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this solves your problem?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381172/how-can-i-make-flexbox-children-100-height-of-their-parent?rq=1

Comment: @Tramonta it doesn’t.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `style` property `height: '100%'` in the `row` view in your `Tab()` function

The first element is not taking 100% of the height because it has less Childs (default behaviour of a `View`, [doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view))

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

const Tab = ({ textNodes }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', height: '100%' }}> //here add height 100%
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', width: 10 }}></View>

        {/* the green view isn’t able to fill parent's height*/}
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', flex: 1 }}>
          {textNodes.map((node)=><Text>{node}</Text>)}
        </View>
      </View>

      <View style={{ height: 10, backgroundColor: "black" }} />
    </View>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 25 }}>
      <Tab textNodes={[1, 2, 3]} />
      <Tab textNodes={[1, 2, 3, 4]} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Using `height: '100%'` makes the tabs stretch till the bottom, in other words, each tab's height becomes that of the screen.