# Vaadin23 FlexLayout and component resize

Tags: css, vaadin, vaadin23

I have FlexLayout with two vertical components:

```
    VerticalLayout gridVerticalLayout = configureGrid();

    form = new SearchForm(employmentService, locationService);
    form.setWidth("25em");

    FlexLayout content = new FlexLayout(gridVerticalLayout, form);
    content.setFlexGrow(2, gridVerticalLayout);
    content.setFlexGrow(1, form);
    content.setFlexShrink(0, form);
    content.addClassNames("content", "gap-m");
    content.setSizeFull();
```

Everything works fine except one thing - when I dynamically (on the `Button` click) add more components to the `form` (component on the right side of the `FlexLayout`), the  `gridVerticalLayout` doesn't occupy the new space at the bottom of the page:

[image]

Is it possible somehow to let `gridVerticalLayout` to automatically growth when the height of the entire page also growth?

**UPDATED**

`content` is added to the `view` class which is extended from `VerticalLayout`. This main `VerticalLayout` is configured with the following:

```
addClassName("all-jobs-view");
addClassName("editing");

setSizeFull();
setPadding(false);
setMargin(false);
```

**all-jobs-view.css**

```
@media all and (max-width: 1100px) {
  .all-jobs-view.editing .toolbar,
  .all-jobs-view.editing .vacancy-grid {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

`gridVerticalLayout` configuration:

```
private VerticalLayout configureGrid() {

    VerticalLayout gridVerticalLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    gridVerticalLayout.addClassNames("vacancy-grid");
    gridVerticalLayout.setPadding(false);
    gridVerticalLayout.setMargin(false);
    
    ....

    grid.setSizeFull();
    grid.addThemeVariants(GridVariant.LUMO_WRAP_CELL_CONTENT);

    gridVerticalLayout.add(grid);

    return gridVerticalLayout;
```

**UPDATED**

devtools info:

[image]

Comment: Could you show how gridVerticalLayout is configured (are you setting any sizes or such on it?) I see a scrollbar there so I'm wondering if that's on the gridVerticalLayout itself, or on a child element?

Comment: Updated the question with the additional info

Comment: Thanks. I suspect that the vertical-layout called vacancy-grid *is* stretching correctly, but the content inside it is not? And you might be able to fix that by setHeightFull on vacancy-grid.

Comment: You could use the browser devtools to check which parts are stretching and which are not. Can't really tell from the screenshot.

Comment: I tried to add `gridVerticalLayout.setHeightFull();` but it didn't help. I added devtools debug info to the question. Vertical layout looks strange and doesn't stretch with the right `form`.

Comment: Yup, the problem seems to be the all-jobs-view layout rather than the vacancy-grid layout. It's not stretching to fill the viewport despite having 100% height. That's usually caused by a missing 100% height somewhere higher up in the layout hierarchy: setting 100% height on a child element usually has no effect unless its parent also has a height defined, since it's a percentage of the parent's height. So I'm guessing there is some other container outside of all-jobs-view that is missing a height.

Comment: Thanks! I checked everything and I have `height: 100%` everywhere.. Maybe it's related to `flex`?

Comment: yeah... it was `flex`. Fixed with help of this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381172/how-can-i-make-flexbox-children-100-height-of-their-parent

Comment: Ah, glad to hear it! Was a bit difficult to tell without being able to inspect the whole layout hierarchy.