# 'full available height' inner div -- why does this work?

Tags: css, flexbox

I got a layout to work in CSS but I don't understand *why* it works. CSS experts, please shed light on what's going on here.

My goal was to have a layout like this:

[image: desired layout]

The salient features are:

1. Fixed height header and footer at the top and bottom of the window
2. A content area taking up the full space between the header and footer
3. The content area has its own scrollbar (i.e. it doesn't push the footer down past the bottom of the screen).

I made it happen using a combination of css flex box and a div inside the content div with 0% height. Against my expectation, the 0% height div stretches to the full available height.

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2wunC/ (it doesn't look quite right because the outer `height:100%` doesn't make sense inside the jsfiddle container).

HTML

```
<div id="everything">
  <div id="header">fixed-height header</div>
  <div id="workspace">
    <div class="docstretch"><div class="docwindow">
      filler text<br>filler text<br>filler text<br>...
    </div></div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">fixed-height footer</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#everything {display:-webkit-flex;-webkit-flex-flow:column;-webkit-align-items:stretch;height:100%;}
#header {height:2em;background:lightgray;}
#footer {height:2em;background:darkgray;}
#workspace {-webkit-flex:1 0 auto;display:-webkit-flex;-webkit-flex-flow:row;}
.docstretch {background:#05c;color:white;width:300px;overflow-y:scroll;}
.docwindow {height:0%;} /* why does this work? */
```

**My question**: the nested divs (docstretch and docwindow) with the inner div having `height:0%` created the content div I wanted, taking up the full 'interior space' of the page and having its own scrollbar. But why? And is this a safe solution?

Comment: do you want like this... http://babysoftblog.com/tablet/eco_energy/

Comment: no -- the eco_energy template interior seems to remain a set height. I want the scrollbar to always take up the full space between header and footer.

Comment: There *is* an instance where Flexbox can be used to get a similar result using a zero height element, but it only works with column orientation.  See this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962468/flexbox-and-vertical-scroll-in-a-full-height-app-using-newer-flexbox-api

Comment: oops, my situation is exactly the same as the answer you linked. I do have a column orientation -- the flex-flow:row is applying to the sub-elements, it's cruft from a more complicated example.

Comment: @amwinter i have tried this by css but i didnt success, maybe some custom jquery would help... i am sure...

Answer (score 0):

If you take away all of the Flexbox properties, you'll see that it has nothing to do with Flexbox at all:

http://jsfiddle.net/2wunC/2/

The problem is that you have `height: 0%`.  Drop the % and it works as you would expect:

http://jsfiddle.net/2wunC/1/

Comment: I tried your fork /2/ (the one with 0%) in a standalone document and the content div collapsed. JSFiddle is confusing the issue by introducing extra containers.

Comment: Which browser?  Opera, Chrome, Firefox, IE9 are all showing the blue div as being completely visible.

Comment: chrome '25.0.1364.172 m'. Did you test in jsfiddle or as a standalone html file?

Comment: Both.  Chrome Version 26.0.1410.43 m

Comment: I'm missing something. You're saying fork 2 displays as non-collapsed?

Comment: Yes.  Not sure that it matters, but using HTML5 doctype.

Comment: doctype fixed it in chrome. But it's not exactly the same. If you restore the flex styles and remove the doctype, the footer will stick to the bottom of the screen.