# Vertical layout with middle box scrollable (not position: absolute)

Tags: html, css

I need something looking very common:

```
+-----------+
|  Header   |
+-----------+
|          ^|
|          ||
|  Scroll  ||
|          ||
|          v|
+-----------+
|  Footer   |
+-----------+
```

But the problem is, that my header can wrap, and so its height can change. So I can not use `position: absolute` to layout page and any other where header size is fixed and known *a priori*. I designed one [solution](http://jsbin.com/oluhoh/14/edit) using `display: table`, but it looks different in every browser, and only works as expected in Chrome.

What would I need to do to adapt this for FF and IE9?

[link (working in chrome only)](http://jsbin.com/oluhoh/14/edit)

Here is picture in order: FF, IE, Chrome (ok)

[image]

My version: FF (20.0.1), IE (9.0.8112.16421 64bit), Chrome (26.0.1410.64 m)

Comment: This question may be of interest, but Flexbox requires IE10+:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962468/flexbox-and-vertical-scroll-in-a-full-height-app-using-newer-flexbox-api.  You'll get exactly what you want in most browsers if you can live without scrolling in those that don't support it.

Comment: @cimmanon this is perfect... but i need IE9 :(

Comment: Yeah, it would be simple if you could have [a fixed height of header](http://pastebin.com/z08LjVLh) via absolute position, but now it is quite a riddle....

Answer (score 0):

You want `overflow-y: scroll`.

Working example:

### [Demo](http://jsbin.com/oturiw/3/edit)

Comment: Does not work on FF :( On IE9 it expands down when header wraps :(

Comment: Cannot confirm that: It's working here on FF ESR 10.0.11 and FF ESR 17.0.4 and IE 9.0.8112.16421 (Windows 7 64-Bit)

Comment: I added picture to my post.

Answer (score 0):

Add overflow-y:scroll to your content div for scroll and max-height to header. This may be help to your query:
see here: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XYgVH/16/)

```
.header{
    max-height: 100px;
}
.content {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: In you example layout height is not preserved.