# No fixed height header & content fills rest of page with auto vertical overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a header on my page. Its content can wrap, so it is not fixed height. The rest of the page should be filled by the content container. When there is too much content in the container it should activate vertical scroll.
I tried many possibilities but always stuck in dead end (position: absolute or display: table). Now I am back to the starting point :(

[Here is the starting point](http://jsbin.com/ifehop/2/edit) of my work. The green container is my page. I use JqueryUI to make it re-sizable, but I am looking for a non JS solution.

Thanks for your time & hopefully your help.

Comment: nope :( your answer does not do the job or i can not apply it.

Comment: @Saram I think this cannot be done without using any javascript.

Comment: I don't know if putting the header inside the containing element is an option. If it is, it's straightforward: http://jsfiddle.net/ZMZGF/

Comment: Or not sure why `display:table` is not an option: http://jsfiddle.net/ZMZGF/1/

Comment: Lastly, you can always go the `calc()` route, although browser support isn't 100% yet. See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-notation

Answer (score 5):

This works:

```
.page {
  background-color: #8f8;
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
}

.header {
  background-color: #fcc;
}

.content {
  background-color: #ccf; 
  overflow: auto;
  height: inherit;
}
```

Comment: +1 This works. Here's the [JSBin demo](http://jsbin.com/oyudif/1/edit) of the above.

Comment: How I understanded it the container should fill the page (100%) of remainder. That's not the case now, is it ?

Comment: @JNDPNT I thought the container (`.page` class) was supposed to be resizable, and the content (`.content` class) was supposed to expad to fill the available space in `.page`.

Answer (score 2):

I think it could be solved like:

```
.page {
  background-color: #8f8;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
}

.header {
  background-color: #fdc;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  background-color: #ccf; 
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /*word-wrap: break-word;*/
}
```

Ok, what I have done:

1. Page: you can put simply height to 200px if you really know the size of the heigh, but it makes more sense to me adding `min-height: 100%` to make the page fill all the space.
2. Header: To allow the header resize when the content changes it is necesary setting its overflow as hidden. This will avoid for displaying any kind of scroll. Of course it must be a block element, like div or then you will have to add `display:block`.
3. Content: Here put the height as 100% of the space, allow the visibility of the vertical scroll only when neded and break words only if the content you will display can make the horizontal scroll to appear.

Finally, to avoid the page going off the bottom put the header as part of the content div.
Ask me for more details.

**UPDATE**: here is the [example](http://jsbin.com/eyolud/8/edit) where I have tested it.

**UPDATE2**
The best I have gotten is [this](http://jsbin.com/eyolud/15/edit):

```
.page {
  background-color: #ccf;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header {
  background-color: #fdc;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content{
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

The only problem it has is that the scroll thinks that what it is scrolling is all the "page" element not only the content, so you can not see the final arrow of the scroll.
I think this could be solved by using javascript, but with css I think there is no better solution.

Javascript possible solution:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
     resizeContent();
});
$(document).load(function(){
  resizeContent();
});
function resizeContent(){
  $('.content').height($(".page").height()-$('.header').height());
}
```

The link with a final solution could be found [here](http://jsbin.com/eyolud/17/edit)

Comment: content goes outside page at the bottom :(

Comment: Just put the header as part of the content. See it here [link](http://jsbin.com/eyolud/8/edit)

Comment: What do you mean as going outside?

Comment: header is also scrolled and hides above top edge (tested with chrome)

Comment: Ok I tried multiple solutions but the fittest is that I have edited. What you want is one of the limitations of using 100% as maximun size and not using min-height. You can do more powerful things using jQuery or other js framework. (Of course it could be done easily with a table element but as I can see it is not what you want)

Comment: Finally the best solution I've found you can checkout it [here](http://jsbin.com/eyolud/17/edit)

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:
Even if many answers are close, I still state `this behavior cannot be achieved only using CSS and NOT having a styling issue` and I'll explain why.

The problem:

- Having the header free to wrap it's content causing it's height to change.
- Having the scrollable area to be resizable **and** needing to fill all it's wrapper.

The solution:

- Many answers were close to achieve this:

  - [Benjamin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16421242/no-fixed-height-header-content-fills-rest-of-page-with-auto-vertical-overflow#comment23764562_16545233)'s [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/uvaduh/1/) looks like it works but actually it has a flaw, please test this with the provided fiddle: 1) Resize the container to make the scrollbar thumb reach half of the scrollbar track height. 2) now select some text and move your mouse down and up, to make the scrollbar move while selecting. This flaw causes the draggable handler used to resize the main area to move up.
  - [Feantury](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16554109/544283) answer's [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/eyolud/17/edit) is in a way, better than Benjamin's because it does not have that bug, but, it still has a flaw: the draggable handler is on top of the down arrow of the scroll bar.
  - [Karl-André Gagnon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16499745/544283)'s [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/ebocen/1/edit) has the same issue as Benjamin's.

Finally:

- [JNDPNT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16481099/544283) dropped some light here: `I don't think what you want is possible in css... You should look into a JS solution I'm afraid.`
- Please don't be too hasty in css, many things are not what they seem to be, css also has to be tested, every re-size in css is not your friend. Many styles could break when re-sizing a window or a container, dragging and dropping, etc.
- Even in highly responsive designs many of them has either a css hack, and/or at least some basic use of javascript and or jquery.

NOTE: I honestly wanted to help the OP, and I'm pretty sure this cannot be achieved with plain css.

---

I don't think it's possible w/o using any javascript, here is a jsbin I made to suit your request, please take a look at this: http://jsbin.com/acirez/1.

This is the result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note: Consider changing the `.page` and `.header` classes to id's instead, since the javascript does:

```
$('div.content').height($('.page').height() - $('.header').height());
```

If you do not wish the horizontal bar to appear just change the `overflow: scroll;` for `overflow-y: scroll;`.

Hope it helps!

EDIT: Added images.

Comment: @ -1 guy: Care to share why? This does **EXACTLY** as the OP requests.

Comment: It's just a single downvote... Is it really worth posting a comment **and** a question on meta? People can vote however they want to

Comment: This does *not* do "exactly" as the OP requests. The OP clearly says "I am looking for a non JS solution". (Yes I was the down-vote.)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to add the following to your #content:

```
  height:100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
```

this gives it a height a height which he stays. The `overflow-y:scroll;` makes the content scrollable after 100px;

If you want more you could give it a min and max height like this:

```
  min-height:100px;
  max-height:600px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
```

in this situation it will keep filling it till the heigh reaches 600px, and then will go in `overflow-y:scroll;`

//UPDATED//

put the position of the content and header to `relative` and apply `height:auto; padding-bottom:50px;` to the #page

Comment: It does not work like i expected. When header wraps and doubles its height the max-height value is not proper, and content exceeds page height :(

Comment: put the positions of the #content and the #header to `position:relative` and set the page height to : `height: auto; padding-bottom:50px;`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you want is possible in css... You should look into a JS solution I'm afraid.

I've tested with table-properties and getting the header flexible is easy. Getting the content to fill up the rest is easy as well... But I fail to get the remaining content scrollable when the text becomes to long. I can't find a solution for that and quite frankly I don't think one exists. Prove me wrong... It would be interesting to find a pure css solution for this :).

This is as far as I get:

http://jsbin.com/ivuvag/1/

Comment: This is one of my dead end. I found solution working olny in chrome so far :(  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168449/vertical-layout-with-middle-box-scrollable-not-position-absolute

Answer (score 1):

Just make the content 100% the height of its parent.

```
.content {height: 100%;}
```

Comment: negative. content height remainds fixed, does not adjust to header height :(

Answer (score 1):

try

```
height:60px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
```

http://jsbin.com/ifuwaz/1/

Comment: heder height can not be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if you can move your DOM, but if you can, I suggest you put your header in the content page. This is not the most egornomic way to do it, but its the only idea i got without JS.

So, put your header in the content and then, set the content `min-height` to 100%. Content will alway fill its parent and if the text is longer than the container, scroll bar will apear.

[Check this](http://jsbin.com/ebocen/1/edit)

Note that the scroll bar are alway there because of the resizable. In your context, it will not be there.

Answer (score 1):

Give the div.content the overflow-y: scroll property, and a height exceeding div.page. I just made it height: 100%. Then hide the overflow on div.page.

```
.page {
  background-color: #8f8;
  height: 200px;
  width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden; 
}

.header {
  background-color: #fcc;
}

.content {
  background-color: #ccf; 
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%
}
```

Now this will cut off the last bit of overflow if the box is really packed, but it's the only solution I can think of without using some js to dynamically resize div.content.

Comment: Had a thought. The bottom part getting cut off can be avoided by adding a spacer div at the bottom of the .content div. 40px of height seems to suffice.

http://jsbin.com/uvaduh/5/

Comment: Looks good, but there is problem with scroll, it hides under bottom of page. If only 50% of content height is visible i can not reach bottom part by scrolling :(

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I'm able to scroll all the way to the bottom of the content.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I'm not quite sure what exactly you want, but here is a go.

http://jsbin.com/asazaq/1/edit

Now there is no non-javascript way to have both the Header & The Content Fill all available space if you don't set the Header's Height to a Fixed value.

Here's a Second one Using Css3's Calc function.

http://jsbin.com/asazaq/2/edit

Maybe thats more to your liking but its not supported in older browsers