# I need scrollbar on inner element, not browser window (viewport)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In the code below, how do I make the `article` container auto grow to consume the remaining vertical space below it, but the scroll bar to remain only for that element.

In other words, I want only the inside of article to scroll and not the entire browser window.

Is there a pure css solution? Or do I need javascript to detect the size of the browser window and adjust the height property of article dynamically?

```css
html, body {
  //height: 100%;    

}
#outer_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
#outer2 {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
#outer2 {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
#container header {
  background-color: gray;
}
#container article {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 0px;
}
#container footer {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer_container">
  <div id="outer1">
    <h2>Outer 1</h2>
  </div>

  <section id="container">
    <header id="header">This is a header</header>
    <article id="content">
      This is the content that
      <br />With a lot of lines.
      <br />With a lot of lines.
      <br />This is the content that
      <br />With a lot of lines.
      <br />
      <br />This is the content that
      <br />With a lot of lines.
      <br />
      <br />This is the content that
      <br />With a lot of lines.
      <br />
    </article>
    <footer id="footer">This is a footer</footer>
  </section>


  <div id="outer2">
    <h2>Outer 2</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ch7n6/907/

It was originally based on the answer to this question:
[Flexbox and vertical scroll in a full-height app using NEWER flexbox api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962468/flexbox-and-vertical-scroll-in-a-full-height-app-using-newer-flexbox-api)

Comment: Why not just add `height: 100%` to the `#outer_container`?  http://jsfiddle.net/ch7n6/911/

Comment: Interesting. I swear I tried this earlier and it didn't work. It's part of the reason I posted the question originally. It works now tho. If you make yours an answer can I accept yours as well? I actually prefer this for all the obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting `position:fixed` to your outer container (http://jsfiddle.net/ch7n6/909/):

```
#outer_container{
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
top:0;
bottom:0;
position:fixed;
}
```

If it doesn't work for your design, you can change the container dimensions using `window.onresize` event.

Comment: that works! Thank you. It has an interesting side effect. The flexboxes #outer1 and #outer2 now grow to the full height of #outer_container. Is this expected? is there a css property I can set so their height depends on their content?

Comment: Yes, there is - 'align-self:flex-start;'. It should be set on both containers (#outer1 and #outer2), and they will stop growing

Comment: boss. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you commented out:

```
html, body {
  //height: 100%;    
}
```

But I think you were on the right track.

By uncommenting that rule, and adding `height: 100%` to `.outer_container`, your layout may be complete.

Try this:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;                   /* uncommented */
  margin: 0;                      /* removes default margin */
}
#outer_container {
  height: 100%;                   /* new; see details below */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
#outer2 {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background-color: lightblue;     /* just for demo */
}
#outer1 {                          /* correction to duplicate ID */
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background-color: lightgreen;    /* just for demo */
}
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
#container header {
  background-color: gray;
}
#container article {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 0px;
}
#container footer {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer_container">
  <div id="outer1">
    <h2>Outer 1</h2>
  </div>
  <section id="container">
    <header id="header">This is a header</header>
    <article id="content">
      This is the content that
      <br />With a lot of lines.
      <br />With a lot of lines.
      <br />This is the content that
      <br />With a lot of lines.
      <br />
      <br />This is the content that
      <br />With a lot of lines.
      <br />
      <br />This is the content that
      <br />With a lot of lines.
      <br />
    </article>
    <footer id="footer">This is a footer</footer>
  </section>
  <div id="outer2">
    <h2>Outer 2</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ch7n6/912/)

To understand how this solution works, and what may have held you up, take a look at these posts:

- [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)
- [Chrome / Safari not filling 100% height of flex parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276)