# React: toggling flexbox screws up height

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a react app with a layout as described here:
[Nested flexbox with 100% height and scrollbar on element (not browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39441543/nested-flexbox-with-100-height-and-scrollbar-on-element-not-browser)

Assume that we go ahead with this implementation from @michael-b:
http://jsfiddle.net/ch7n6/911/

Additional functionality is that I have buttons that toggle whether or not certain flexboxes are in the DOM or not.

e.g. my react component has render logic that looks like:

```
{ viewState.showBoxA ? <div id="outer1"></div> : null}
{ viewState.showBoxB ?  <section id="container" >
                          <header id="header" >This is a header</header>
                          <article id="content" ></article>
                        </section> : null }
{ viewState.showBoxC ? <div id="outer2"></div> : null }
```

I have some buttons that toggle the value of showBoxA, showBoxB and showBoxC so that the relevant element either hides or shows.

If I hide and then show section#container the height of article#content gets screwed up and it is no longer 100% the height of section#container.  It's height drops to 0. If i set a height property in article#content, it just becomes that height instead of being recalculated.

Is this normal react / CSS behavior? What would i need to do so that if I toggle section#container the height of section#container is rendered as expected?

Comment: using `visibility` property will work for you?

Comment: as i understand, its more desireable to use a null component rather than toggling visibility?