# How to create Docking with CSS3 Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, docking

This is not duplicate, because answers here , [CSS3 Flexbox full-height app and overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251447/css3-flexbox-full-height-app-and-overflow) and [Flexbox and vertical scroll in a full-height app using NEWER flexbox api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962468/flexbox-and-vertical-scroll-in-a-full-height-app-using-newer-flexbox-api/14964944#14964944) are only half and combining both does not yield correct results.

[image]

Currently I have done this through JavaScript, I have calculated width/height of container and divided things based on docking criteria.

I have tried using both answers and I don't know how to make this layout because I have little less knowledge of flexbox, I have read every article on first page of google search, but looks flexbox direction works only on one direction, either you can create flexible boxes row wise or column wise.

```
<div class="dock-panel">
   <div class="dock-top" style="height:30px">Header</div>
   <div class="dock-left" style="width:200px">Tree View</div>
   <div class="dock-fill">Nested Fill Element</div>
   <div class="dock-right" style="width:100px">Status Panel</div>
   <div class="dock-bottom" style="height:30px">Footer</div>
</div>
```

The reason I have defined inline styling here because I am creating set of classes useful for docking, and other users will import that CSS and will write height/width as per their needs in different or inline CSS. So I do not know in advance about height/width.

Class dock-fill should use all the space available and if I resize my window, except dock-fill everything should be docked and only one of size parameter should resize, for example, in top, height remains same, but width is 100%.

I can do this by adding container within container, but that breaks our UI hierarchy.

Comment: Are you able to add extra elements or are you stuck with this markup?  Should dock-left/dock-right scroll as well if their contents should overflow?

Comment: Yes overflow auto may be added and will be added if necessary, but my markup is fixed, it is already working well with JavaScript, can't change lots of pages, if it is possible through flexbox, then I can leave JS only for IE, and use flexbox and should have native advantage.

Comment: The second example you linked to with vertical scrolling is only possible with column orientation (row orientation would allow you to have horizontal scrolling that works the same way).  You would have to use an extra element with Flexbox, there's no way around it:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/w2x1b8mn